# Yield from in listcomp or genexpr difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, generator-expression, yield-from

Why the result is different?

```
In [19]: [(yield from (1, 2)) for x in [1]]
Out[19]: <generator object <listcomp> at 0x0438B3C0>

In [20]: list(_)
Out[20]: [1, 2]

In [21]: ((yield from (1, 2)) for x in [1])
Out[21]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0438B480>

In [22]: list(_)
Out[22]: [1, 2, None]
```

Comment: As that answer explains, it's somewhat of a bug, the `None`s come from the yield inside the generator.

Comment: The list comprehension also produces the `None`, you just don't see it added to the list. This is because using `yeld` or `yield from` inside a list comprehension or a generator expression is actually *not supported*. The language grammar permits it but the compiler produces non-sensical bytecode for the code in question.